# PHP script to get data from Elasticsearch on another server

Tags: php, elasticsearch, server

I have a PHP script installed on a web host server. It features a search bar and a button. After inputting information into the search bar and clicking the button a query will be sent to Elasticsearch which should return a result.

This worked fine on my local server setup with WAMP. One of the differences here though is that Elasticsearch itself is running on another server (Debian 9).

The Script (with the external IP redacted):

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;
$client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts(['externalIP:9200'])->build();
$es = $client;

echo "<div class='search'>
        <form action='index.php' method='get' autocomplete='off' class='search_form'> 
            <label>         
                <input type='text' name='q' placeholder='Søk her'>
            </label>
                <label><input type='submit' value='Søk' name='s'></label>
            </form>
        </div>";

if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $q = $_GET['q'];
    $query = $es->search([
        'index' => 'aksjeregisteret2017',
        'size' => 20,
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'must' => [
                        'multi_match' => [
                            'query' => $q,
                            'fields' => ['message', 'Navn Aksjoner', 'Orgnr', 'Selskap',
                                'Aksjeklasse', 'Navn Aksjoner', 'Fodselar/Orgnr', 'Postnr',
                                'Antall Aksjer', 'Antall Aksjer Selskap'],
                            "minimum_should_match" => "50%"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);
}

if($query['hits']['total'] >=1 ) {
    $results = $query['hits']['hits'];
}

//var_dump($results);


?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Søk i Aksjoneregisteret</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php if (isset($_GET['q'])) { ?>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Orgnr</th>
                <th>Selskap</th>
                <th>Aksjeklasse</th>
                <th>Navn Aksjoner</th>
                <th>Fodselar/Orgnr</th>
                <th>Postnr</th>
                <th>Poststed</th>
                <th>Antall Aksjer</th>
                <th>Antall Aksjer Selskap</th>
            </tr>

            <?php foreach ($results as $r) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $r['_source']['Orgnr'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r['_source']['Selskap'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r['_source']['Aksjeklasse'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r['_source']['Navn Aksjoner'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r['_source']['Fodselar/Orgnr'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r['_source']['Postnr'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r['_source']['Poststed'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r['_source']['Antall Aksjer'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $r['_source']['Antall Aksjer Selskap'] ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    <?php } else { echo "no result"; } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that instead of returning the table with data it returns nothing. Just a blank page after loading for a while. No errors.

One thing that could be wrong is how we have installed the PHP script. We cannot use a terminal on our web host so we used composer to create the elasticsearch PHP vendor folder on the linux server (the one with Elasticsearch installed) and then moved it directly into a folder on our web host together with the script. Is this supposed to work or are there any problems by doing it this way? Is there another way to do it?

By using the external IP + port (9200) in the browser we get to see this page:

[image]

If I'm not wrong that should mean the connection to Elasticsearch is open? So using the same externalIP + Port in the script should make us able to get a result?

Any ideas about what I've done wrong?

Comment: It looks like a lot of mess code wise. I would recommended to keep all the queries on a back end and do not mix them with front end. 
Going back to your issue I would recommend dumping the query as a JSON and preforming a CURL request to Elastic cluster or through KIBANA interface. You need to check if the query you created is correct in a first place. 
Let us know if it returns any data and we troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out that the above does not work on the web host server because that server lacks certain features that are required for Elasticsearch PHP.

We moved the script to a VPS and set it up there with little to no modifications and it worked.

If you're going to use Elasticsearch scripts on a web host server where they can't let you install new libraries then make sure they have the requirements to run it first. The requirements for Elasticsearch PHP can be found on this page: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_installation_2.html

They are:

```
PHP 7.0.0 or higher
Composer
ext-curl: the Libcurl extension for PHP (see note below)
Native JSON Extensions (ext-json) 1.3.7 or higher
```

The web host server did not have the Libcurl extension and so the script would not work.